# How to annotate count of an already annotated value?

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a model named `Order` with a `timestamp_delivered` (datetime field). Model Order has driver associated with it. I want to get the number of days each driver has delivered orders.

I am trying the query below:

```
Order.objects.annotate(
    date=Cast('timestamp_delivered'), DateField()
).values(
    'driver_id'
).annotate(
    days=Count('date')
)
```

but got the error:

> KeyError: date

I tried running the command below as well:

```
Order.objects.values(
    'driver_id'
).annotate(
    date=Cast('timestamp_delivered'), DateField()
).annotate(
    days=Count('date')
).values_list(
    'driver_id', 'days'
)
```

Got the output

`[(Driver1, 1), (Driver2, 1), (Driver2, 1)... ]`

However, the output I am expecting is something like:

`[(Driver1, 2), (Driver2, 4), (Driver3, 8)... ]`

Comment: Please post the `Order`  model code. Hard to figure this out without it.

Comment: @manassehkatz
class Order(models.Model):

    driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver)

    timestamp_delivered = models.DateTimeField()

Answer (score 0):

The use of `values` causes the annotations before it to be lost, so that cause your key error. If you keep going with your second solution you'll run into a similar problem.

The trick is to do a count on a modified column. The `TruncDate` function helps out with that:

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate

DeliveryOrder.objects.
  values('driverid').
  annotate(deliverydays=Count(TruncDate('timestamp_delivered'), distinct=True))
```

*Verified in the Django shell*